# Remove URL from "Fetch as Google" - in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google, google-search-console, search-engines, fetch-as-google

I need to remove a URL from *Health -> Fetch as Google* in Google Webmaster Tools.

Is it possible?

Comment: Any solution found?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option on the screen and the help file doesn't mention it, so no.

Comment: is possible to contact Google support to remove URL?

Comment: You could use the Webmaster forums http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/webmasters. Why do you want it removed? The fact that you've asked them to crawl it once doesn't mean they will index it.

Comment: I made some mistakes in url. That is the reason why I am asking..

Comment: That tools just lets you check a particular URL. If the URL is wrong then it won't work, but no harm is done.

Comment: @paulmorriss any solution to this problem now?

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove an url from the list. Like paulmorriss said, there is no harm in simply trying again if you made a typo error in the URL. You get your 500 fetches reset once a week.

> > You can use this tool to fetch up to 500 URLs a week per Webmaster Tools account
> >     https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=158587

If you want to remove an url from the index then when you are in Webmaster Tools go to Optimization > Remove URLs and follow the instructions.

[image]

Comment: Hi. this is for removing url from search result. I am asking about how to remove the url available in Health -> "Fetch as Google".